# PowerShell Copy-Item Method Fails - Brackets in Filename

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell (v.1) to copy over only files that match a pattern. The file naming convention is:

```
Daily_Reviews[0001-0871].journal
Daily_Reviews[1002-9887].journal
[...]
```

When I run it, the method "Copy-Item" complains:

**Dynamic parameters for cmdlet cannot be retrieved. The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: Daily_Reviews[0001-0871].journal

+ Copy-Item <<<< $sourcefile $destination**

The error is due to the "[" and "]" in the file names. When I remove the left and right brackets, it works as expected. But looks like PowerShell 1 doesn't have the -LiteralPath flag so is there another way to get Copy-Item to work in PowerShell 1 with file names that contain brackets?

```
$source = "C:\Users\Tom\"
$destination ="C:\Users\Tom\Processed\"

if(-not(Test-Path $destination)){mkdir $destination | out-null}


ForEach ($sourcefile In $(Get-ChildItem $source | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Daily_Reviews\[\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\].journal" }))
{

  Copy-Item $sourcefile $destination
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, after researching this more I found a workaround:

```
$src = [Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($sourcefile)
Copy-Item  $src $destination
```

Comment: If the brackets are in the directory name, better use this :

`$src = [Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($sourcefile.FullName)`

Answer (score 2):

`$_` references the currently-referenced argument; you can't use it the way that you are here because that's outside the pipeline.

```
$source = "C:\Users\Tom\"
$destination ="C:\Users\Tom\Processed\"

if(-not(Test-Path $destination)){mkdir $destination | out-null}


ForEach ($sourcefile In $(Get-ChildItem $source | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Daily_Reviews\[\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\].journal" }))
{

  Copy-Item -literalpath $sourcefile $destination
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the change that you suggested and I get the same exact complaints from Copy-Item...Weird stuff. I wonder if it's the brackets in the filenames? –

Comment: It's because of the "[" and "]" in the file names. When I remove the left and right brackets, it works as expected. Needs to be able to parse files with brackets though

Comment: The square brackets require that you use `-literalpath` (always wondered when I'd need that) when calling `copy-item`. I've amended my code.

Comment: @alroc Without `-LiteralPath` [globbing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088) takes place, so you need the option when a literal file or folder name contains wildcard characters.